# how to search in vantage point trees?

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, graph-algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to understand vantage point trees and how to use them so in order to do that I created simple example and tried to solve it using vantage point trees and here it is:

suppose we have S={5,0,6.9,7} and we want to execute q=8 (search for the nearest neighbor to q in S) how to do that?

My solution is the following:

First: construction the tree:
[image]

second: perform search:

according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantage-point_tree#Searching_through_a_vantage-point_tree) I have to find the distance between q=8 and the vantage point which is now 7 and this will be equal to 1 and since it is less than the mu (the median of distances of each point to vantage point) which is 2 then I go to branch that contain the closer points which is left and by that i go to node 6 but this is wrong answer since the nearest neighbor is either 7 or 9.

My question:

1- is the constructed tree correct? if not please correct it with explanation.

2- in search what am I missing? would some one please explain to me how to perform search applying it to my example?

Comment: I am not sure you understand the full concept of the vp-tree - every node (or can be define for all tree as one value) need to have property of `r` (distance / radius)

Comment: @dWinder yes I now that every node have mu which  distance between all points and the chosen vantage point for that node am I correct? now based on the that I constructed the tree ( the vantage point is chosen randomly from the points for simplicity) so is my tree correct?

Comment: What is your distance for this tree? `1`? From your root it is look like but the sub tree of `5,9,0` contradict that. Do you want to build vp-tree with distance `1` starting from `5`?

Comment: @dWinder the mu for node 7 is 2, for node 5 is 4.5. I build the tree as follow: for every node I choose vantage point randomly from the points then I take the median of distances from all points in that node to the vantage point for that node ten every point that have distance from the vantage point of that node that is mu goes to the left child else go to right child and I repeat that until no points left please if this method not correct provide me with right tree explaining steps.

Comment: Maybe Wikipedia is missing part - check http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=130 - the current node should be add the the result array at each step

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to clarify a couple of things first.

1. If you want to know the first k values ***without*** using Vantage Point Tree you will need to sort ***all*** the data and pick the first k elements.
2. If you want to know the first k values using Vantage Point Tree you will need to sort ***some*** data and pick the first k elements.
3. In the special case where each element in S is one-dimensional. KDTree and Vantage Point tree are similar.
4. Vantage Point tree is made for high dimensional elements in S.
5. Tau is a hiperparameter.

- If Tau is too small, only a few elements will be shown. Maybe less than k (so the search is useless).
- If Tau is too big, almost all the dataset will be evaluated.

Knowing this let solve your problem.

I have S={5,0,6,9,7}
I want to know the closer value of 8.

> VP CONSTRUCTION

- Random or *not so random* selection of the first Vantage Point.

I'll pick 0 as a Vantage Point.

- mu of the first Vantage Point calculation.

If i take mu(1) as 6.05.

1. The data *INSIDE* the point tree will be 0(the vp),5,6.
2. The data *outside* the point tree will be 9,7.

- Random or *not so random* selection of the second Vantage Point OUTSIDE the first one.

I'll pick 7 as a Vantage Point.

- mu of the second Vantage Point OUTSIDE the first one.

1 will divide the data into 7(vp) and 9.

- Random or *not so random* selection of the second Vantage Point INSIDE the first one.

I'll pick 5 as a Vantage Point.

- mu of the second Vantage Point INSIDE the first one.

1 will divide the data into 0 and 5(vp),6.

> VP Search

Closer friend of 8

Let's choose Tau equals to 1.

- First step

Distance between vp(1)=0 and 8 is greater than tau + mu(1).

**All the points INSIDE VP(0) can be ignored**

- Second step

Distance between vp(2 Out)=7 and 8 is less than tau + mu(2 out), but greater than tau-mu(2 out).

**All the values should be considered**

Distance between vp(2 Out)=7 and 8 is less than tan-mu(2 out).

**All the points OUTSIDE VP(0) can be ignored**